# Where can I get a "Welcome to Quarks" mug?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

This is a merchandise question. If it's not appropriate to the forum then please let me know the rule and I'll delete the question.

DS9 "The Quickening":

> WORF: How did you do it?
>
> O'BRIEN: Do what?
>
> WORF: I ordered a glass of prune juice from the replicator in the
>   Defiant's mess. **This is what it came in.**
>
> (**The mug is emblazoned with Quarks. Free refill. Limit one per
>   customer. When tilted, the jingle plays.**)
>
> KIRA: If all your little advertisements aren't purged from our systems
>   by the time I get back from the Gamma Quadrant, I will come to
>   Quark's, and believe me, I will have fun.

[image]

This mug is what came out of the replicator. When Worf turned it sideways to drink out of it, it played the "Welcome to Quarks" jingle.

I've searched all over the net. I can't find where to buy one.

This guy cleaverly shows how to make one: http://sinkhacks.com/come-to-quarks-the-mug/

He also has a funny video with it at that link (the video is also on youtube).

Does anybody know where I can get an authentic Quark's mug, that looks like the one in the photo, and plays the jingle when turned sideways to drink out of it?

Comment: Hmm, I suspect this is off-topic, but I'll make sure because there's a part in me that thinks this might be okay...

Comment: @N_Soong I want one of these so bad, I'm almost willing to follow the directions on that link.

Comment: This appears to have been made as a custom prop. Note also that the sound is definitely added in post-production rather than actually coming from the mug

Comment: @Richard When I was in Vegas a few years back I went to Star Trek:The Experience. It was awesome. At the end of the simulations there was a gift shop. All I wanted was a Tribble. As I went through it to my dismay I didn't see one, then all of a sudden, walah! by the register was barrell full of tribbles. When you squeezed them, they shook and squealed. Somebody has since stolen my tribble, I think it was one of my brothers. But anyway, I was hoping maybe there was a good outlet for things of this nature and I could purchase a mug such as this.

Comment: This should probably be moved to the meta site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping is offtopic